# uncaught exception: Call to StartUpload failed in uploadify integration with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have integrated uploadify with codeigniter.i can't able select images while clicking the select photos.

MY View file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Uploadify V3 &amp; CodeIgniter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Capsone-System2" >

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url;?>assets/js/jquery/uploadify_31/uploadify.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header">Uploadify V3 &amp; CodeIgniter</h1>

    <p>This is a simple tutorial demo showing Uploadify V3 working with CodeIgniter 2.1.2</p>
    <?php echo form_open_multipart(); ?>
    <ul class="unstyled">
        <li>
            <?php echo form_upload('userfile','','id="userfile"'); ?>
            <?php echo (isset($error)) ? $error : ''; ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php echo form_button(array('content'=> 'Upload', 'id'=>'upload-file', 'class'=>'btn btn-large btn-primary')); ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
<!-- End Of Main Content -->

<!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo base_url;?>assets/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>')</script>-->
<script src="<?php echo base_url;?>assets/js/jquery/uploadify_31/jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<script src="<?php echo base_url;?>assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var base_url = '<?php echo base_url; ?>';
        alert(base_url);

        $('#upload-file').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#userfile').uploadify('upload', '*');
            alert(base_url);
        });

        $('#userfile').uploadify({

            'debug':true,
            'auto':false,
            'swf': base_url + 'assets/js/jquery/uploadify_31/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader': base_url + 'uploadify_v3/do_upload',
            'cancelImg': base_url + 'assets/javascript/jquery/uploadify_31/uploadify-cancel.png',
            'fileTypeExts':'*.jpg;*.bmp;*.png;*.tif',
            'fileTypeDesc':'Image Files (.jpg,.bmp,.png,.tif)',
            'fileSizeLimit':'2MB',
            'fileObjName':'userfile',
            'buttonText':'Select Photo(s)',
            'multi':true,
            'removeCompleted':false,
            'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
                alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller File

I have error uncaught exception: Call to StartUpload failed

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * @property CI_Upload $upload
 */

class Uploadify_v3 extends CI_Controller
{

    public $view_data = array();
    private $upload_config;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('url', 'form'));
        $this->load->view('uploadify_v3', $this->view_data);
    }

    public function do_upload()
    {
        $this->load->library('upload');

        $image_upload_folder = FCPATH . '/uploads';

        if (!file_exists($image_upload_folder)) {
            mkdir($image_upload_folder, DIR_WRITE_MODE, true);
        }

        $this->upload_config = array(
            'upload_path'   => $image_upload_folder,
            'allowed_types' => 'png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|tiff',
            'max_size'      => 2048,
            'remove_space'  => TRUE,
            'encrypt_name'  => TRUE,
        );

        $this->upload->initialize($this->upload_config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
            echo json_encode($upload_error);
        } else {
            $file_info = $this->upload->data();
            echo json_encode($file_info);
        }

    }

}

/* End of file uploadify_v3.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/uploadify_v3.php */
```

I have spent more time..still now i can't fix this error..please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too had the same problem, it was a security issue because I was hosting the flash .swf file on a separate domain eg: static.mysite.com

Make sure your swf file and post handler script are hosted on the same domain that you are accessing the site from.

Or if you need to add cross domain posting then see here:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/cross-domain-xml-for-streaming.html